# Jenkins job keeps waiting for next available executor forever (user dependent)

Tags: jenkins

Depending on the user who triggers the build, the build starts immediately or stays in the queue forever waiting for next available executor. The build node is completely free. The number of executors is 6.

I already tried:

- Disabling the blocking jobs
- Configuring no blocking jobs at all

The multijob project has project-based security, which allows the users to build, cancel, read and see the workspace.
The current configuration of my jobs already worked in the past.
The jenkins master is not the node for which a free executor is being waited (the job is tied to a slave).
The job is a `MultiJob` Project and starts many other jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was solved. The cause of the problem was the installation of the "Authorize Project" plugin" and the selection of "Run as User who Triggered the Build" as Strategy. Changing it to "Run as SYSTEM" solved the problem. The configuration of this plugin is done under "Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Access Control for Builds"